# Keras Predict before softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

So I have trained a model with the following layout:

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(200))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10))
    # compile model
    train_temp = 1
    def fn(correct, predicted):
        return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=correct, logits=predicted/train_temp)

    opt = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=fn, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

and then trained the network for 30 epochs.
Then I created adversarial examples with the source code of Nicholas Carlini, found in his github repo, and just changed the path to the model I trained before.
The attack does run through perfectly and the console output says that an adversarial example is found for every target class, but when I feed the images to my network with my own script, they get classified correctly about 90% of the time.

Here is the function I use to actually save the images of the attack to .png files:

```
def show(img, fname):
    """
    Save Images as files
    """
    ext = ".png"
    # if adversarial example save to different folder
    base1 = '/Users/user/Desktop/NN/output/adversarial/'
    #
    base2 = '/Users/user/Desktop/NN/output/original/'
    if "original" in fname:
        filename = base2 + fname + ext
    else:
        filename = base1 + fname + ext
    #np.save(os.path.join('output'), filename, img)
    fig = np.around((img + 0.5)*255)
    fig = fig.astype(np.uint8).squeeze()
    pic = Image.fromarray(fig)
    #pic = pic.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pic.save(filename)
```

And this is the function I use to feed the adversarial images to my network:

```
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, grayscale=True, target_size=(28, 28))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 1 channel
    img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    # prepare pixel data
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img / 255.0
    return img

# load an image and predict the class
def run_example():
    # load the image
    img = load_image('/Users/user/Desktop/NN/output/original/original_0_3.png')
    img2 = load_image('/Users/user/Desktop/NN/output/adversarial/adversarial_09_4.png')
    # load model
    model = load_model('/Users/user/Desktop/NN/models/mnist', compile=False)
    l = model.get_layer(index=-1)
    l.activation = keras.activations.linear
    model.save('/Users/user/Desktop/verification/testmodel.h5')
    model = keras.models.load_model('/Users/user/Desktop/verification/testmodel.h5')
    for i in range(len(img2)):
        t = model.model.predict(img2[i:i+1])
    print(t)
run_example()
```

Now Carlini mentions on his github that the predictions have to be made before softmax - and I thought I had accomplished this with the model.get_layer(index=-1) - but somehow this does not seem to fix it.
I am lost here a bit, as this is my first adventure with ML :)
Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.
Basically I would just want to have a script that feeds my adversarial examples crafted with the CW L2 attack to my neural network and validate, that they get classified wrongly.
Otherwise I would not understand why the CW L2 attack counts as so strong, if the images get classified correctly just by adding softmax?

Thank you!

EDIT:

So the original test_attack provided by the author, seems to correctly classify the adversarial examples like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        data, model =  MNIST(), MNISTModel("models/mnist-distilled-100", sess)
        attack = CarliniL2(sess, model, batch_size=9, max_iterations=1000, confidence=0)

        inputs, targets = generate_data(data, samples=10, targeted=True,
                                        start=0, inception=False)
        timestart = time.time()
        adv = attack.attack(inputs, targets)
        timeend = time.time()
        imgstamp1 = 0
        advers = "adversarial"
        orig = "original"
        j = 0

        print("Took",timeend-timestart,"seconds to run",len(inputs),"samples.")

        for i in range(len(adv)):
            print("---------------------")
            imgstamp1 += 1
            pred = model.model.predict(inputs[i:i+1])
            print("Prediction class original:", np.argmax(pred))
            originalclass = np.argmax(pred)
            name = orig + "_" + str(originalclass) + "_" + str(j)
            if i % 9 == 0:
                j += 1
                show(inputs[i], name)
            advpred = model.model.predict(adv[i:i+1])
            advclass = np.argmax(advpred)
            name = advers + "_" +str(originalclass)+ "_" + str(advclass) + "_" + str(j)
            show(adv[i], name)
            print("---")

            print("Adversarial example classification: ", np.argmax(advpred))
```

All I want to achieve is to a) save the adversarial examples to files, which seems to be working, as the images I do get, show perturbations, so I assume they are correct. and b) I want a "classifying.py" script, that simply feeds the adversarial images to the same network that the attack was launched against and have it classify them - which should get me the same results as during the crafting of the images. I just dont know where my mistake is, I assume my classifying script seen above does something wrong, as the authors mention, that prediction should be done without softmax.
Hope that its now clear where my problem is - sorry, not a native speaker and super new to ML as well :/